# How many instances of a Java Enum are available without looping?

Tags: java, enums

```
for(MyEnum myEnum : MyEnum.values()){
count++;
}
```

But is there a better way using oridinal or something else ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about: `MyEnum.values().length`?

Answer (score 1):

`values()`  returns array.Just get the `length` of it.

```
int size = MyEnum.values().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `values()` methode returns an array of type T (`T[]`). Just retrieve the length of that array via the length attribute.

Example:

```
enum Operations {
    ADD, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY
}

System.out.println Operations.values().length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also receive the ordinal value of the enum constant via

```
for ( MyEnum value : MyEnum.values() )
{
    System.out.println( "ordinal: [" + value.ordinal() + "]" );
}
```

**Java FTW! :D**